# Why document.write is used for writing ads?

Tags: javascript, document.write

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) I'd like to understand if document.write is a bad practice why everybody uses it for writing ads on the page?

Comment: You need to understand _why_ `document.write` is considered a bad practice: it is more difficult to maintain, easy to get wrong, restricted in what it can do... but what it does do, it does perfectly well. It's like saying pitchforks are deprecated as cutlery... till you try to prepare a meal for a giraffe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a practical programming problem.

Comment: My hunch is that it works and that code is more than 10 years old. Why change it now?